# calculate R2 from sum of squares of residuals and number of sample is known only

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

I was trying to solve a mathematical problem of multiple linear regression. There is a model given as

```
Y= ß0 + ß1X2 + ß2X3 + ε
```

And the sum of squares of residual i.e. SSRes=4.312. The number of sample i.e. n=108.
I need to find the value of coefficient of determination, R2. Which is the ratio of SSReg/SST. I know that SSRes=SST-SSReg. But how to calculate R2, if I don't know any of SST or SSReg.
SST=Total Sum of Squares, SSReg=Sum of Squares of Regression.
Please suggest any possible approach to find R2 from these given data only.

Answer (score 0):

if you know these 108 data, then SST = sum((y - mean(y))^2), R2 = (SST - SSRes) / SST.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I do not have those 108 data. I have only data of residual and number of sample and regression model.